# How to convert NAN to 0 in php

Tags: php, sql, nan

I am calculating percentages of values in a database table, however, when there is no values, the function returns NAN, i would like the function to return 0 instead, the function am using is:

```
function calculate_percentages($atts){         
    global $wpdb;
    $postid = get_the_ID();
    $myrate_name = "sql_table_name";
    $total_count = $wpdb->get_var( "SELECT SUM(rates) FROM $myrate_name WHERE post_id=$postid");
    $top = $wpdb->get_var( "SELECT SUM(rates) FROM $myrate_name WHERE  rating = 5 AND post_id=$postid");
    $top_avarage = round($top/$total_count*100);
    return $top_avarage;
```

Comment: Your query is returning a string? What is the value of  `$total_count` and `$top`?

Comment: You can try `$top_avarage = $top_avarage == „NaN“ ? 0 : $top_avarage;`

Comment: No, don't use `„“`

Comment: But really, how is your server configured so that the warning does not show? :s http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/3656bb055887749dd48969ea03a6ef9d2170acfa

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You get `NAN` because `$total_count` is `0` or something that evaluates to `0` and you cannot divide by `0`.  So check if it's `0` and if so set the result to `0`, if not then do the calculation:

```
$top_average = $total_count != 0 ? round($top/$total_count*100) : 0;
```

Answer (score 1):

You have a php function you could use [is_nan](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.is-nan.php)

```
$top_average = !is_nan($top/$total_count*100) ? round($top/$total_count*100) : 0;
```

Comment: Shouldn't `$top_average` be set to zero when `is_nan`?

Comment: _Warning: Division by zero_